# Some Manage Jenkins Links Don't Work - Nginx Reverse-Proxy, Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, nginx, jenkins, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've setup 2 different versions of Jenkins on the same Windows 2012 R2 OS. Jenkins v1.590 is running behind an Apache Tomcat web server and Jenkins 2.164 is running as a Windows service. Both Jenkins instances are accessible via HTTPS.

To make this work, I am running Nginx as a reverse-proxy that redirects all requests to https://jenkins.company.com/jenkins to the Tomcat server and https://jenkins2.company.com to the Jenkins 2.164 Windows service.

All is working well EXCEPT for unusual behavior on Jenkins v1.590. The problem I am having is when I access **some** of the links under Manage Jenkins they redirect to localhost.

Here are the links that work fine:

- **Configure System**: Redirects to: https://jenkins.company.com/jenkins/configure
- **System Info: Redirects to**: https://jenkins.company.com/jenkins/systemInfo
- **Load Statistics**: Redirects to: https://jenkins.company.com/jenkins/load-statistics

Then there are links that DO NOT work:

- **Configure Global Security**: Redirects to: https://localhost/jenkins/configureSecurity/ with error "localhost refused to connect"
- **Manage Plugins**: Redirects to: https://localhost/jenkins/pluginManager/ with error "localhost refused to connect"

and many others.

I can STILL get to these links if I copy into a new windows and add a / at the end, ex: https://jenkins.company.com/jenkins/configureSecurity/ works fine.

I am not sure why I am getting these discrepancies in Jenkins v1.590. Just to note, I made this change very recently and before the Nginx installation, all of the links were working fine.

Below are my configs:

**Nginx:**

```
upstream tomcat_server {
    # Tomcat is listening on default 8080 port
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  jenkins.company.com/jenkins;

    ssl_certificate C:/nginx1.15.12/certs/jenkins/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key C:/nginx1.15.12/certs/jenkins/server.key;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_connect_timeout      240;
        proxy_send_timeout         240;
        proxy_read_timeout         240;
        # note, there is not SSL here! plain HTTP is used
        proxy_pass http://tomcat_server;

    }
}
```

**Tomcat Config:**

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
    port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" 
    proxyName="localhost"
    proxyPort="443"
    scheme="https"/>

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I had to change the proxyName on the Tomcat server to the url. This ended up being the solution:

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           proxyName="jenkins.company.com"
           proxyPort="443"
           scheme="https"/>
```